# Remove an elemet from an array of struct in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to implement an  functionality to remove an element from an array of struct in spark scala.For the date "2019-01-26" I want to remove the entire struct from the array column. Following is my code :

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    
    val df=Seq(("123","Jack",Seq(("2020-04-26","200","72","ABC"),("2020-05-26","300","71","ABC"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"))),("124","jones",Seq(("2020-04-26","200","72","ABC"),("2020-05-26","300","71","ABC"),("2020-06-26","200","70","ABC"),("2020-08-26","300","69","ABC"),("2020-08-26","300","69","ABC"))),("125","daniel",Seq(("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF"),("2019-01-26","200","70","DEF")))).toDF("id","name","history").withColumn("history",$"history".cast("array<struct<infodate:Date,amount1:Integer,amount2:Integer,detail:string>>"))
    
    scala> df.printSchema
    root
     |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- name: string (nullable = true)
     |-- history: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- infodate: date (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- amount1: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- amount2: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- detail: string (nullable = true)
```

[image]

> So the for the date 2019-01-26 , I want to remove the struct in which
> it is present so that it is removed from the array column.I want a solution like this.

[image]

I manage to find the solution but it involves lot of hardcoding
and I'm searching for a solution/suggestion that is optimal.

Hardcoded solution:

```
val dfnew=df
 .withColumn( "history" , 
  array_except(
   col("history"),
   array(
    struct(
     lit("2019-01-26").cast(DataTypes.DateType).alias("infodate"),
     lit("200").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).alias("amount1"), 
     lit("70").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).alias("amount2"), 
     lit("DEF").alias("detail")
    )
   )
  )
 )
```

Is there any way of optimally doing it with one filter condition only
on date "2019-01-26", which removes the struct/array from the array
column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an expression / filter here.  Obviosuly it's a string so you can replace the date with a value so that there is even less hard coding.  Filters are handy expressions as they let you use SQL notation to reference sub-components of the struct.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

df.withColumn( "history" , 
  expr( "filter( history , x -> x.infodate != '2019-01-26' )" )
 ).show(10,false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |name  |history                                                                                                                                     |
+---+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123|Jack  |[[2020-04-26, 200, 72, ABC], [2020-05-26, 300, 71, ABC]]                                                                                    |
|124|jones |[[2020-04-26, 200, 72, ABC], [2020-05-26, 300, 71, ABC], [2020-06-26, 200, 70, ABC], [2020-08-26, 300, 69, ABC], [2020-08-26, 300, 69, ABC]]|
|125|daniel|[]                                                                                                                                          |
+---+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @matt-andruff , is there any way we can filter out two dates instead of one using this filter expression, two dates - "2020-04-26" and "2019-01-26" . I tried out this code expr( "filter( (history , x -> x.infodate != '2019-01-26') & (history , x -> x.infodate != '2020-04-26') )" ) but didnt work.

Comment: I would think: expr( "filter( (history , x -> x.infodate != '2019-01-26' or  x.infodate != '2020-04-26') )"